# Flash Builder 4 spaces instead of tabs?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Is it possible to configure Flash Builder 4 to indent using spaces instead of tabs?

I've enabled `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Insert spaces for tabs` but it still inserts tabs. I've tried editing files with no tabs but it still inserts tabs.

What's strange is that `Insert spaces for tabs` works in Eclipse but not Flash Builder, which is built on Eclipse. Perhaps there's a bug in Adobe's portion of Flash Builder.

I'm running Flash Builder 4.0.0.272416 on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: After changing this setting: Did you closer/reopen the workspace?  Did you close/reopen Flash Builder?  Did you close/reopen the files you were editing?

Comment: Yes, I've tried reopening the file, reopening the project, and relaunching Flash Builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you changed:

> Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Insert spaces for tabs

won't work.

I'm not sure if there ever was a way to get it to work in FB4, but in FB4.5 you can with:

> Preferences > Flash Builder > Editors > Indentation > Insert using > spaces

Comment: Unfortunately FB4 doesn't have `Indentation` settings. This Adobe article (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_productivity.html) claims to have fixed this in FB4, they also acknowledge it was broken in FB3.

Comment: As far as I can remember about FB4, it never worked to change the setting you mentioned; and it was causing me pain. Of course if it's now fixed, you just need to update ;) .

Comment: Okay, I was incorrect. I found the `Indentation` setting and it works. I'm sure not what `Insert spaces for tabs` is for.